# Time limit exceeded on codeforces

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been stuck on this [problem](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1492/B) for a pretty Long while. I always get "Time limit exceeded" when I submit the code.
My solution is to input the items of the array then determine the largest number in the array and diplay it along with the elements following it and so on.
How can I make my algorithm more efficient?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int T, n;
    cin >> T;
    while (T--) {
        //inputting p[n]
        scanf_s("%d", &n);
        int* p = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            scanf_s("%d", &p[i]);
        }

        while (n != 0) {
            //*itr = largest element in the array
            auto itr = find(p, p + n, *max_element(p, p + n));
            int index = distance(p, itr);

            for (int i = index; i < n; i++) {
                printf("%d\n", p[i]);
            }
            //deleting element by decreasing n:
            n = index;
        }

        delete[] p;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're searching through the array twice. Spend a few minutes thinking about what `max_element` returns.

Comment: Looks like your link is broken and according to my firewall it launches a malicious attack. That is the end of my helpful mood. Please fix it without detour via a hiding/shortening service.

Comment: @bassel27 I had a look at your history and discovered that you have neve accepted any answer to your many questions. Is it because you don't know how to do it, or because you consider that none of the answers were good enough? Of course you have perfectly the right to think so.

Comment: I fixed the link

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm sorry what do you mean by "accepting an answer"? I'm kinda new here.

Comment: It is me that makes this notice. When an answer helps you, you can accept it by clicking a button just near the answer. Only one possibility per question. Takes time to select the best if several. No obligation. It indicates future readers  that the answer is correct. And the answerer gain 15 points.

Comment: @Damien Accepting does not imply "correct". Usually the asker is the wrong person to judge that. Accepting only means the very subjective "helped me most". Many questions have strictly speaking incorrect accepted answers. They are usually accompanied by highly upvoted contradicting answers. Which does not make the "accept" tick wrong.

Comment: @Yunnosch Effectively. I should have said *... that the answer was considered helpful by OP*.

Comment: @Damien Sorry for nitpicking, but that misunderstanding is widely spread, especially among new users who did not take the [tour] (hint, hint, bassel27), and causes confusion and sometimes frustration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You solution is O(n^2), too slow.

A O(n) solution is obtained by iteratively calculating the position of the max element until a given index `i`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
//using namespace std;

int main() {
    int T;
    std::cin >> T;
    while (T--) {
        //inputting p[n]
        int n;
        std::cin >> n;
        std::vector<int> p(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            std::cin >> p[i];
        }
        std::vector<int> max_before(n);
        max_before[0] = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
            if (p[i] > p[max_before[i-1]]) {
                max_before[i] = i;
            } else {
                max_before[i] = max_before[i-1];
            }
        }

        while (n != 0) {
            int index = max_before[n-1];
            for (int i = index; i < n; i++) {
                std::cout << p[i] << " ";
            }
            //deleting element by decreasing n:
            n = index;
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't your solution's time complexity O(n^2) too? It has  a for loop nested inside the while(n!=0) loop. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, it is O(n). There are 2 loops indeed, but the size of the outer loop is decreasing  as much as the the size of the inner loop. At each iteration of the inner loop, a number is written, and there a `n` numbers to write. So `n` is the complexity.

Comment: I don't quite understand you honestly. The while loop is executed n times and the nested for loop is executed (n-index) times for each n time. I think the time complexity will be O(n*(n-index)) which is O(n^2) for the sake of simplicity. What did I get wrong?

Comment: If the outer while loop is executed n times, then the inner loop is executed 1 time, as it would correspond to `max_before[i] == i`. Try to execute this algorithm manually.